# Intersection of less than ogive and more than ogive is median proof.

Tags: statistics

I was always told that the abcissae of the intersection of the less than ogive and the more than ogive gives the median for a grouped classed data (with exclusive data classes). I wanted to prove this.

Suppose there are $m$ class intervals. Let the $i^{th}$ class interval ($i \in [m]$) be given by $ [L_i, U_i]$  and have frequency $f_i$ ($f_i \in \mathbb{N}$). Let class size of $i^{th}$ class interval be given by $h_i = U_i - L_i$. (Since the classes are of exclusive type, $L_{i+1} = U_{i}$). And let $N = \sum_{k=1}^m f_k $ be the total number of data points.

Let $L(x) : [U_1,U_m] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ represent the function for the less than ogive. Then:
$$
L(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k = 1}^i f_k &\text{ if } x = U_i \text{, }i \in [m] \\
\sum_{k = 1}^i f_k + \frac{f_{i+1}}{h_{i+1}}(x - U_i) &\text{ if } U_i < x < U_{i+1} \text{, }i \in [m-1]
\end{cases}
$$
Let $M(x) : [L_1,L_m] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ represent the function for the more than ogive. Then:
$$
M(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k = i}^m f_k &\text{ if } x = L_i \text{, }i \in [m] \\
\sum_{k = i}^m f_k - \frac{f_{i+1}}{h_{i}}(x - L_i) &\text{ if } L_i < x < L_{i+1} \text{, }i \in [m-1]
\end{cases}
$$
Extrapolate $L(x)$ and $M(x)$ to $[L_1,U_m]$ by extending them as constant functions outside their defined domain. Then define $g(x) : [L_1,U_m] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:
$$ g(x) = L(x) - M(x) $$ 
By continuity and montonicity of $g(x)$ on $[U_1,L_m]$, it is easy to see that it has exactly one zero. Now the problem arises. How to find the zero? Unless we know which class interval $[L_i,U_i]$ the zero belongs to, we cannot solve for the point of intersection of the line segments within a class interval. Since $g(x)$ is continuous, I was hoping to use the IVP to find the class interval i.e. show $g(L_k)g(U_k) < 0$ for some $ k \in [m]$.

As a guess, I tried the median class interval. Let $l$ be the median class interval i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^l f_k \leq \frac{N}{2} < \sum_{k=1}^{l+1} f_k$.  I was able to show that $g(L_l) < 0$ but for $g(U_l)$:
\begin{align}
g(U_l) &= L(U_l) - M(L_{l+1}) \\
       &= \sum_{k=1}^l f_k - \sum_{k= l+1}^m f_k \\
       &= 2\sum_{k=1}^l f_k - N \\
       &= 2( \sum_{k=1}^l f_k - \frac{N}{2}) < 0      
\end{align}
Now what do I do? How to find the zero? Or is there an easier approach to find the zero of $g(x)$?

[The formula for median is $ M = L_l + h_l\frac{\frac{N}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{l-1}f_k}{f_l}$.]

Comment: Once data have been reduced to classes, information is lost and it is not possible in general to find the exact median of the original data before binning.

Comment: @BruceET But you can always use linear extrapolation to find that value of $x$ for which the cumulative frequency equals $N/2$. That is how the median formula mentioned in the last line is derived. It is known that the abcissae of the intersection of less than ogives and more than ogives also gives that median value. That is what I wanted to prove.

Comment: "Linear extrapolation' assumes uniform distribution of observations within bins. That assumption may be convenient, but in general it is baseless.

Comment: I don't know how to justify the assumption used. But that formula and result are well documented and used in many competitive exams. I wouldn't dismiss it just like that, I wanted to find a proof for the result which I have been using for so many years.

Comment: Perhaps someone who shares your enthusiasm for estimating the median in this way can be of help.

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake earlier: If $l$ is the median class interval, then it should be: $\sum_{k=1}^{l-1} f_k< \frac{N}{2} \leq  \sum_{k=1}^{l} f_k$. Then the answer comes out nicely: By formula $M = L_l + h_l\left(\frac{\frac{N}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{l-1}f_k}{f_l}\right)$, and by the intersection of less than and more than ogives, you get: $M = L_l + h_l\left(\frac{\frac{N}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{l-1}f_k}{\frac{f_l+f_{l+1}}{2}}\right)$.